# How to define the probability for never occurred event between players

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I would like to find a probability between opponents that have never played with each other.

I would like to explain what I mean in an example.

Player A won  m times against Player B  and never lost a match against Player B.
Player B won  n times against Player C  and never lost a match against Player C.

If Player A and Player C play a match, As a sense,  we can easily say that Player A has big advantage against Player C even though they have never played a match before.

I would like to find a formula to define the probability for such events that we need to formalize such kind of probability events.

**Firstly, I want to define limit possibilities**

---

A won all matches against B. $P_{A/B}=1$

B won all matches against C. $P_{B/C}=1$

Let's define probability before a real match between A and C
the probability of winning A against C:  $$P_{A/C}=1$$

---

---

A lost all matches against B . $P_{A/B}=0$

B lost all matches against C . $P_{B/C}=0$

Let's define the probability before a real match between A and C

The probability of winning A against C:  $$P_{A/C}=0$$

---

### Other limit possibilities:

A won all matches against B. $P_{A/B}=1$

B lost all matches against C. $P_{B/C}=0$

We can not say anything about a real match between A and C. We can consider their chances are same as limit definition for this condition.

### $$P_{A/C}=1/2$$

---

A lost all matches against B. $P_{A/B}=0$

B won all matches against C . $P_{B/C}=1$

We can not say anything about a real match between A and C. We can consider their chances are same as limit definition for this condition.

### $$P_{A/C}=1/2$$

**More Generally**

---

A won m times against B in n games. $P_{A/B}=\frac{n}{m}$

B won x times against C in y games. $P_{B/C}=\frac{x}{y}$

I would like to find an estimated probability before a real match between A and C
 $$P_{A/C} =f(m,n,x,y)$$

Some properties of the function $f(m,n,x,y)$ must satisfy that:
The limit conditions:

- $f(0,n,0,y)=0  \tag{1}$
- $f(0,n,y,y)=\frac{1}{2} \tag{2}$
- $f(n,n,0,y)=\frac{1}{2}  \tag{3}$
- $f(n,n,y,y)=1  \tag{4}$

*Other important property:*

A won x times against B in y games. $P_{A/B}=\frac{x}{y}$

B won m times against C in n games. $P_{B/C}=\frac{m}{n}$

We should have the same probability with previous result. $$P_{A/C} =f(x,y,m,n)=f(m,n,x,y)$$

Thus,

- $f(m,n,x,y)=f(x,y,m,n)  \tag{5}$

Other property is:

$$P_{C/A} =1-P_{A/C}$$

- $f(y-x,y,n-m,n)=1-f(m,n,x,y)$

Because of property 5 above, we can write that

$f(y-x,y,n-m,n)=f(n-m,n,y-x,y)$

- $f(n-m,n,y-x,y)=1-f(m,n,x,y)  \tag{6}$

I have found the candidate function that satisfies these 6 conditions:

$$f(m,n,x,y)=\frac{1}{2} (\frac{m}{n}+\frac{x}{y}) =\frac{P_{A/B}+P_{B/C}}{2} \tag{7}$$
$$P_{A/C} =\frac{P_{A/B}+P_{B/C}}{2} \tag{8}$$

I want to extend the idea for 4 players and 
I tested the candidate function(7) for 4 players conditions but the candidate function did not work

### Let's see the status for 4 players.

A won m times against B in n games. $P_{A/B}=\frac{n}{m}$

B won x times against C in y games. $P_{B/C}=\frac{x}{y}$

C won k times against D in z games. $P_{C/D}=\frac{k}{z}$

I want to find  $$P_{A/D} =g(m,n,x,y,k,z)$$

Limit conditions:

1. $P_{A/D}=g(0,n,0,y,0,z)=0  $
2. $P_{A/D}=g(0,n,0,y,z,z)=\frac{1}{2}$
   /Absolutely, C is the most powerful player but We cannot say anything between A and D before a real match, so we need to give same chance for A and D before a real match. (C>[A,B,D])
3. $P_{A/D}=g(0,n,y,y,0,z)=\frac{1}{2}$ 
   /Absolutely, B is the most powerful player 
   but we do not know the level between A and D. (B>[A,C,D])
4. $P_{A/D}=g(0,n,y,y,z,z)=\frac{1}{2}$ 
   /Absolutely, B is the most powerful player but we do not know the level between A and D.(B>[A,C,D])
5. $P_{A/D}=g(n,n,0,y,0,z)=\frac{1}{2}$ 
   /Absolutely, The worst player is B but we do not know the level between A and D.([A,C,D]>B)
6. $P_{A/D}=g(n,n,0,y,z,z)=\frac{1}{2}$ 
   /Absolutely, The worst player is B but we do not know the level between A and D.([A,C,D]>B)
7. $P_{A/D}=g(n,n,y,y,0,z)=\frac{1}{2}$ 
   /Absolutely, The worst player is C but we do not know the level between A and D.([A,B,D]>C)
8. $P_{A/D}=g(n,n,y,y,z,z)=1$

other properties:

9. $g(m,n,x,y,k,z)=g(m,n,k,z,x,y)=g(x,y,m,n,k,z)=g(x,y,k,z,m,n)=g(k,z,x,y,m,n)=g(k,z,m,n,x,y)$
10. $P_{D/A} =1-P_{A/D}$  thus $g(n-m,n,y-x,y,z-k,z)=1-g(m,n,x,y,k,z)$

EDIT:
I have found  an candidate function $P_{A/D}$ for 4 players : It satisfies all 10 conditions above .

$$P_{A/D}=\frac{1}{2}(P_{A/B}+P_{B/C}+P_{C/D})-\frac{1}{2}(P_{A/B}P_{B/C}+P_{B/C}P_{C/D}+P_{A/B}P_{C/D})+P_{A/B}P_{B/C}P_{C/D}$$

My candidate function for 5 players ${{A,B,C,D,E}}$ and known values $P_{A/B},P_{B/C},P_{C/D},P_{D/E}$
$$P_{A/E}=\frac{1}{2}(P_{A/B}+P_{B/C}+P_{C/D}+P_{D/E})-\frac{1}{2}(P_{A/B}P_{B/C}+P_{A/B}P_{C/D}+P_{A/B}P_{D/E}+P_{B/C}P_{C/D}+P_{B/C}P_{D/E}+P_{C/D}P_{D/E})+\frac{1}{2}(P_{A/B}P_{B/C}P_{C/D}+P_{A/B}P_{B/C}P_{D/E}+P_{B/C}P_{C/D}P_{D/E}+P_{A/B}P_{C/D}P_{D/E})$$

I would like to generalize the problem for n players . What is the function for n players case?

I haven't seen such probability formula during my search. Please let me know if you know a research about it.
Thanks 
Best Regards

Comment: It doesn't seem like a purely mathematical problem.  Take boxing.  Frazier seemed to have an advantage over Ali.  Ali beat Foreman in their 1 fight.  But Foreman completely dominated Frazier.  A vs B and B vs C here tell us nothing useful about A vs C.

Comment: @WDS  I just mention probability calculation before the event occurs. For example, the probability of having head for a fairy coin is 1/2 but you can get 2 times tail after flipping 2 times it. The probability of an event does not show what you will get in the future.

Comment: This is what rating systems are for, for example ELO: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system